# How to throw an array exception in php

Tags: php, exception

So I have an error message that gets thrown in one file

```
$error_message = "Error received for " . $service . ": " . $_r['status'] . "\n" . "Message received: " . $_r['errors'];
throw new My_Exception($error_message);
```

and in another file I have

> ```
> try {
>     //blah blah
> } catch( My_Exception $e ) { 
>     var_export($e->getMessage());
> }
> ```

The problem, however, is that $_r['errors'] is an ARRAY and it get $e->getMessage() just prints it as "Array". How can I modify this code to access the array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To convert a complex data-structure like an array into a string (e.g. for error messages), you can make use of [`print_r`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/print_r) and setting it's second parameter to `TRUE`:

```
... ": " . print_r($_r['status'], TRUE) . "\n" ...
```

Answer (score 17):

The problem is that You're trying to merge array with a string. It'll always end like this.

Maybe You should pass to exception an array, so You can later make use of it?

```
<?php
class myException extends Exception {

    private $params;

    public function setParams(array $params) {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function getParams() {
        return $this->params;
    }
}

// later it can be used like this:
try {
    $exception = new myException('Error!');
    $exception->setParams(array('status' => 1, 'errors' => array());

    throw $exception;
}
catch (myException $e) {
    // ...
}
?>
```

Comment: This is bad form as it breaks the basic interface of exceptions. If you need to pass some values - just add a method that collects and stores them.

Comment: +1 Perfect. Now that object is gaining, rather than losing, functionality.

Answer (score 2):

we can using json format

```
   throw new Exception(json_encode(['type'=>'error','isExit'=>'true','title'=>'SystemConfigError']));
```

and in the catch

```
        catch (Exception $error)
    {
        var_dump(json_decode($error->getMessage(),JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

so your example code is kinda bad, but assuming

```
$_r['errors'] = array(
    'Message 1',
    'Message 2',
    'Message 3',
    'Message 4',
    'Message 5',
);
```

Then

```
$error_message = "Error received for " . $service . ": \n" . impolode("\n", $_r['errors']) . "\n" . "Message received: " . $_r['errors'];
throw new My_Exception($error_message);
```

The key is taking your array of error messages and concatenating them all together with newlines (or whatever)

But I kinda agree with the comment that you may be using the Exception framework wrong. Can you post what you are trying to do?

The general rule of thumb is that you throw an exception for each unique event. You dont collect a bunch of error messages and then throw them all at once.